# Java Command Line on Different OS's

Tags: java, linux, operating-system, processbuilder

Okay, so I am using process builder to launch an independent java process from the current java process, using the code:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-jar", "C:\\Users\\MyName\\Desktop\\Test.jar");
    pb.start();
```

to test it, just as a simple questin, will the command always be "java -jar something.jar," on all operating systems? and if not, what are the formats for mac and linux?

Comment: Hardcoding '/' or '\' in file path is not recommended. Use system property `File.separator` instead.

Comment: Its just test code.... Im gonna switch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is complicated.  Some of the complications are:

1. Your `ProcessBuilder` will not work if `java` is not on the search path.
2. Your `ProcessBuilder` will give you the version of java on the search path, which may be different to the version that you want to use; e.g. if the user has installed multiple versions of java.
3. You are using a pathname for the JAR file with windows syntax.  That won't work on other platforms.
4. You are using the `java` launcher.  On Windows that will launch the JVM with its own console window.  (And that is rather crude / ugly.)  You may want to use `javaw` instead.  But then `javaw` only exists on Windows.

---

TL;DR - what you have written will work (with some modifications) if you make some assumptions about the Java installation, but those assumptions are not always valid.

---

My suggestion would be to launch a shell script or batch file that runs the JAR file, and provide different versions for different platforms.  Do it in a way that allows the administrator / expert user tweak the script to address issues relevant to their deployment of your software.

Comment: woops hit post by accident, -- continuing, however, 1. I know that my user must have java on the path, 2. I'm gonna compile in like, 1.5, so most versions should work, 3. that was just testing code, I will use File.seperator, 4. it is critically it also works on linux so... so to conclude, due to the environment the users have, I can make those assumptions about the java installation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this works for most linux, mac and windows. I don't really know it gets hairy or not on more obscure linux platforms though.

Linux: https://askubuntu.com/questions/101746/how-can-i-execute-a-jar-file-from-the-terminal

Mac: [Executing a jar on mac 10.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18858363/executing-a-jar-on-mac-10-8)

Sorry for the kind of lame articles, but they illustrate the point.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check out Apache Commons Exec. Here is a question related to it. [How to run a java program using apache commons-exec?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15416750/how-to-run-a-java-program-using-apache-commons-exec)